# Link not working Inside Div

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I am a beginner and have a really stupid question to ask. I created these two divs and have linked two pages with them. Now the problem is, the 2nd link (Sign In) works but the first one won't.

**Here's the HTML:**

```
         <div id="intro-img" class="animated fadeIn"> <a href="signUp.html" class="btn">Sign Up</a>

         <div class="wallpaper" alt="wireframe"></div>

         <div id="intro-img" class="animated fadeIn"> <a href="signIn.html"class="btn1">Sign In</a>

         <div class="wallpaper1" alt="wireframe"></div>
```

**And here's the relevant CSS**:

```
#intro .btn {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0;
    top: 150px;
    z-index: 40;

            }

#intro .btn1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0;
    top: 280px;
    left:5px;
    z-index: 50;

            }
```

Comment: What is not working?  The link to a new page or displaying it?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup 

Thank you people for your interest, It is resolved now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to close the div or maybe you don't check the correct name singUp.html

```
<div id="intro-img" class="animated fadeIn"> <a href="signUp.html" class="btn">Sign Up</a><div id="intro-img" class="animated fadeIn"> <a href="signUp.html" class="btn">Sign Up</a> </div>
```